# If/else statement for certain case

Tags: java, recursion, user-input, towers-of-hanoi

Hi this is a towers of hanoi puzzle program. Right now I am having trouble with getting the program to solve for 3 discs if when prompted 'Enter the number of discs' is blank (i.e. enter key is hit without inputting any integer value).

*My if/else statement inside my hanoi method is where I think the problem is. I commented out where I think the problem is. How do I get the program to just solve for just 3 discs if nothing is input when prompted for 'Enter the number of discs'?***

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TowerOfHanoi4 {
    static int moves = 0;
    static boolean displayMoves = false;
   static int blank = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the Number of Discs : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int iHeight = scanner.nextInt();
        char source = 'S', auxiliary = 'D', destination = 'A'; // name poles or
                                                                // 'Needles'

        System.out.println("Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves");
        Scanner show = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = show.next();
        displayMoves = c.equalsIgnoreCase("v");


        hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
        System.out.println(" Total Moves : " + moves);
    }

    static void hanoi(int height, char source, char destination, char auxiliary) {
        if (height >= 1) {
            hanoi(height - 1, source, auxiliary, destination);
            if (displayMoves) {
                System.out.println(" Move disc from needle " + source + " to "
                        + destination);
            }
            moves++;
            hanoi(height - 1, auxiliary, destination, source);
        }
//       else (height == blank) {                                  //I think the problem
//          hanoi(height - 1, source, auxiliary, destination);//Lies with this
//          moves++;                                          //else
//          hanoi(height - 1, auxiliary, destination, source);//statement         
//       }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this program say "if the input is blank?" You're comparing the input in `scanner.nextInt();` to the value 3. Just because you called the variable name "blank" do you expect the program to wait for a blank input?

Comment: yes, I do expect it to wait for a blank input. 'Nothing' is entered

Comment: But where in your program do you check for a blank input? The only place you refer to inputs being blank is that you chose to name a variable "blank."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the check immediately after getting the input itself instead of checking it in the method.

```
String height = scanner.nextLine();
int iHeight = height.trim().isEmpty() ? 3 : Integer.parseInt(height);
// The above code snippet will read the input and set the iHeight value as 3 if no input is entered.
```

And remove the `else` part from the `hanoi()` method.

*Edit:* In case the option to show steps is not required, you need to add an `if` and show the option to display steps in it.

```
String height = scanner.nextLine();
int iHeight = 3; // Default is 3
if (!height.trim().isEmpty()) { // If not empty
    iHeight = Integer.parseInt(height); // Use that value

    // And display the option to show steps
    System.out.println("Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves");
    Scanner show = new Scanner(System.in);
    String c = show.next();
    displayMoves = c.equalsIgnoreCase("v");
}
```

Comment: Awesome I didn't see that! One more question, if nothing is entered, how would I get the program to skip the 'Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves' step?

Comment: In that case, you need to have an `if-else` in the code. But why would you want to do that? If nothing is entered, then the default value is 3 right? why not let the user choose to see the steps for the height 3?

Comment: It is just what the instructions specified. If nothing is entered, then it solves for 3 discs and only displays the 'Total Moves' and does not list the moves. Weird I know

Comment: Check the edit in the answer. I guess that should do the trick for you.